# JSON data is invalid

Tags: json, curl, cmd

I am trying to cURL an API for speech transcription, but am getting the error `JSON data is invalid`. It is very likely that this is an API specific error, however, I was wondering whether it was an issue with my cURL command.

```
curl --request POST --url "https://api.assemblyai.com/transcript" \
--header "authorization: abc123" --data \
"{audio_src_url: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.assemblyai.com/audio/8-7-2018-post/7510.mp3}"
```

The documentation is the first example at this [link](https://docs.assemblyai.com/#quickstart) and I am using Windows cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need double quotes around the keys and the values.

```
curl --request POST --url "https://api.assemblyai.com/transcript" \
--header "authorization: abc123" --data \
"{\"audio_src_url\": \"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.assemblyai.com/audio/8-7-2018-post/7510.mp3\"}"
```

Comment: I get the same error in addition to `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 84`. What is the difference between how Windows treats `\`` and `"`?

Comment: I didn’t include any backticks in my answer. Just single quotes. Does the API documentation mention setting a content type header? Because I feel like it would make sense to set that to "application/json". Also, make sure you don’t have any smart quotes going on. Some non-code text editors will make your quotes curly (smart) and you don’t want that.

Comment: Sorry I mean `'`... my bad

Comment: The docs don't necessitate explicitly including a content type header.

Comment: I think we may have to use double quotes and escape them on windows. I’ll update my answer with something for you to try. I don’t have a windows computer.

Comment: You're right, I had to escape the internal double quotation marks! Thanks for the help, I'll set your answer as correct after you edit in the escape characters.